# English phrases \ idioms for - taking personal responsibility for your happiness

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

In my language we have phrase -

```
The rescue of a drowning man is the drowning man's own job
```

Which you can meet in English too and roughly meaning - taking personal responsibility for your happiness.

I wonder, if there is more common similar phrases exist ?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wouldn't say the idiom you mean is about responsibility for your own happiness. Rather, it's about being responsible for your whole life. The idiom you have given is about a drowning man. I think for him survival is more important than happiness.

As for the English equivalent, I've remembered the words of Audrey Hepburn: 
"**If you ever need a helping hand, it's at the end of your arm**", which means 
**help yourself and God will help you**.

Comment: Thank you very much,  this is what i want. You are right, "happiness" is not in the spot here. Stackexchange is really need to ask people reason for down voting.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I was able to help. You are right about down voting. But after all, it's just one's subjective opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The following formulation is associated with Eleanor Roosevelt, though she may not have said exactly this: "No one can make you feel inferior without your consent." A number of instances of a similar expression, "No one can make you unhappy without your permission," can be found via Google.

Comment: My mistake to emphasis about happiness. But this phrase  "No one can make you feel inferior without your consent." is about my question and good one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**by one's bootstraps**   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bootstraps) *or pull oneself up by one's (own) bootstraps*

> to improve or become a success by one's own efforts